# How to fix 'could not find array type for data type text[]' in TypeORM

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am using below function to create options for pass findAndCount in the repository.

```
buildFindOptsForSearch(select: Array<string>, condition: object, options: SearchableOptions): any {
    const optCondition = {};

    Object.keys(condition).forEach( (key) => {
        if (Array.isArray(condition[key])) {
            optCondition[key] = Any(Array(condition[key]));
        } else {
            optCondition[key] = Like(`%${condition[key]}%`);
        }
    });

    const opts: any = { where: optCondition, order: {} };

    if (select.indexOf("*") === -1 && select.length !== 0) {
        opts.select = select;
    }

    if (options.limit) {
        opts.take = options.limit;
    }

    if (options.offset) {
        opts.skip = options.offset;
    }

    if (options.orderBy) {
        opts.order[options.orderBy] = options.order || "ASC";
    }

    return opts;
}
```

Issue is when I pass array paramters, I am getting an error "[QueryFailedError] could not find array type for data type text[]"

How do I use Any in TypeORM ?